# Xml.etree.ElementTree Supporting AND in Xpath Predicates

Tags: xpath, elementtree

First of all, is it right that `and` is not supported in predicates? The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) of ElementTree does not explicitly mention this.

For example: `element.find(./trace/string[@value='1' and @key='nuksf']/..)`

Executing the above expression results in a `SyntaxError: invalid predicate`. When I only test for one attribute, e.g., `element.find(./trace/string[@value='1']/..)` everything works as expected. Is there any way to use the `and` keyword in a predicate?

Comment: Try once like this: `./trace/string[@value='1'][key='nuksf']` and i am suspecting on double quote `"`

Comment: The double quote was just a typo here on SO. Encapsulating each attribute test instead of using `and` works!

Comment: Thank you @AmrendraKumar! This error still occures using html5lib version 1.1, python version 3.7.9. The correct call without typos should be: `element.find("./trace/string[@value='1'][@key='nuksf']")`